# External table is not in the expected format in c# - After deployed

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

When I'm trying to read the excel sheet(.xlsx) using c# it's working but this can be only debugging mode i.e when I try to run from the visual studio debugging mode it's working I'm getting the excel sheet and I shaved into DB.

```
Then I have deployed IIS server 6.1 and I tried into client system I'm getting 
an error like 


External table is not in the expected format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: External table is not 
in the expected format.

Source Error: 
  Line 339:            {
  Line 340:
  Line 341:                oledbConn.Open();
```

**My Question**

```
Why it's not working after deployment? 
I have tried the client and server machine(which I hosted) both I'm getting the same error
```

**My Code:**

```
var connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;\"";

oledbConn.Open();
OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Project Structure with DG No$]", oledbConn ))
{
    OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    oleda.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: There are three different type of commands 1) Text (like your select query 2) Table 3) Stored Procedure.  You may need to specify type : cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Comment: Hi Friend, Thanks for the quick reply. i haved mentioned command.type also but not working. Everthing working fine but after deployement not working...

Comment: You are using the ACE driver version 12 which is for Office 2007.  Check in program files the version of ACE you have installed : C:\Program Files\Common Files\system\ado\msado12.dll. You either need Microsoft Office Installed or you have to install the ACE Runtime library of msdn.

Comment: Thanks, dude! i have checked there is msado15.dll is there instead of msado12.dll. Could you please help me how to install msado12.dll?

Comment: First try ACE.OLEDB.15.0.  You would either need to install office 2007 or get the runtime from : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4438.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Office

Comment: Let me explain what i have in my server. List of dlls @ my server msader15.dll, msado15.dll, msadomd.dll, msador15.dll, msadox.dll, msadrh15.dll. And i have installed MS acess 2007. still i'm getting same problem after deployement. But its working on debugging mode. -@jdweng

Comment: Thank you very much! finally, I have fixed. I need to mention Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\" instead of Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;\"